# Using a parameter multiple times in a single line bash command

Tags: bash, shell

I occasionally need to run a command such as:

```
mv "very-long-file-name.x" "very-long-file-name.y"
```

I would like to achieve this without repeating the very long file name twice...

I know how to do this by passing just "very-long-file-name" once to a bash script which would then use $1 ... but how can I do this without a script?

Comment: You can define as many copies as you need and use them earlier. 
`vlf=$very-long-file-name`
`vif2=$vif`
`mv "$vif.x" "$vif.y"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` lets you define variables before the command, like this:

```
X="very-long-file-name" bash -c 'mv "${X}.x" "${X}.y"'
```

But beware that variables defined this way are only defined for the environment that command runs in, not in the parent shell environment. So you have to have that `bash -c` in there, and put single-quotes around the the subshell argument string, otherwise the variables will be interpreted in the parent shell, where they're not defined.

Comment: running exactly this in the OS X terminal I'm getting: `mv: rename .x to .y: No such file or directory`

Comment: however, this works: `export X="very-long-file-name" && mv "${X}.x" "${X}.y"`

Comment: @GJ. Oops, I'd forgotten that that syntax trick only defines the variable for the subshell. I've updated my answer to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

Make use of **Brace Expansion**:

```
mv very-long-file-name.{x,y}
```

<sup>*Do not quote the `{x,y}` part. Do not add a space before or after any brace or the comma.*</sup>

After expansion, this will result in:

```
mv very-long-file-name.x very-long-file-name.y
```